# Как скопировать/переименовать файл на golang?

Tags: golang

Есть файлы `file_new.exe` и `file.exe`.

Как из приложения на go переименовать `file_new.exe` в `file.exe` либо скопировать с заменой?

Comment: Та ну я согласен, что простой вопрос. Начал гуглить и не мог найти. Со всеми бывает. Вот кому-то понадобится- будет на форуме сразу ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
package main

import (
     "fmt"
      "os"
)

func main() {

      //Путь начального  и конечного файлов
      err :=  os.Rename("new.txt", "index.txt") 

      if err != nil {
          fmt.Println(err)
          return
      }

}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.